# Liquibase default table space

Tags: java, database, liquibase

is it possible to configure default tablespace for liquibase? Precisely, i need to specify tablespace for liqui's service tables, such as "databasechangelog".

Comment: You probably could create those tables manually (and specifying the tablespace) before running Liquibase for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not something that is currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

This feature's implementation progress can be tracked in https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1225.

Comments on the issue state that it's mostly done, at least in master branch.

Comment: I don't see that there's any progress:
1 Vote for this issue, 2 Start watching this issue,
Created: 26/Oct/12 9:39 AM, Updated: 10/Mar/16 1:24 PM